# Android App Debugging in Win Vista Home - SP 2 - Processor Issue

Tags: android, debugging, processor

Very new in Android app. 
Installed Eclipse, SDK, configured AVD but not able to debug my "Hello World" app in Eclipse running on Windows Vista Home Premium SP2.

When I am trying to debug - popup appears

The JRE Instance default XSLT processor does not support debugging would you like to debug using the default Xalan 2.7.1 processor instead?

If I click OK, the Android.Manifest.out.out.xml opens in Eclipse and it says "Document is empty. Right mouse click here to insert content."

What to do at this point. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

You are mistakenly trying to debug the .xml file not the project.
You need to go back to the package explorer pane, right click on the project, then select 'debug configurations' from 'Debug as'. Then click top left icon (new config), give it a name like 'helloconf'  and select your project from under the 'Android Application' divider. Then give it a an AVD target from under the target tab. Apply and debug.

Comment: Yaaapi ... Thank you very much. Now I can go to the 2nd chapter of the book.